# user credential validation after user rename

Tags: c++, windows

Using [KB180548](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180548) in a native c++ application, the user can log in in this application with his Windows credentials.
However, a strange bug appears: if the user is renamed, the old(original) name still work with this authentication method, but the new name does not!
What is the problem? Why does Windows not acknowledge the name change in all instances?

On a side note, a long time ago, when interfacing with another software, which also used Windows accounts for log in, I found something similar in their software:
first, they had a limitation in that a username containing spaces did not work. To remedy that, I renamed the user. But this renamed user still did not work. Creating a new user with the same name worked...

Comment: come on, is this the Friday effect? 9 views?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. The Control Panel based user renaming is a farce. To really change the username, as opposed as just the full name, type netplwiz in a command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Windows caches credential information until the next time you log in.  This is how you can log into your corporate laptop, even when that laptop isn't currently connected to your company's domain controller.